# DoubleClick Conversions Differing to GA Goal Completions

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, goal-tracking, doubleclick-ad-exchange

I use GTM to manage the various tags on my site.
Amongst others, I have a GA tag as well as a separate DoubleClick Floodlight tag. 
I use GA to track goal completions on my confirmation page (destination goal), and in GTM I use that same destination goal URL to trigger the firing of the DC Floodlight tag.

As far as I'm concerned the goal completions in GA should match those in DC. They don't however as GA has ones that DC doesn't.

I'm trying to work out why this could be the case. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions of things I could check?

So far the only theory I could come up with is that perhaps some browser extensions could be blocking the DC tag and not the GA tag as perhaps it sees the DC tag as more invasive?
 Does that sound reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

It is highly likely that ad blockers block anything from DoubleClick by default.   DoubleClick serves a lot of ads.

However, Google Analytics isn't typically blocked by ad blockers by default.